# How to import wrl with polylines

Tags: solidworks

is this possible to import a .wrl to SOLIDWORKS 2019 SP 2 without losing polylines? I tried to import VRML 1.0 and VRML 2.0 formats in both cases it didn't work.

I expected someting like this [model I open in freeWRL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRfNQ.png) but [in solidworks I can't see any polylines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lTDS.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get anwser in SolidWorks forum.

"SOLIDWORKS is completely ignoring the IndexedLineSet elements in the WRL file.  You can replace a valid polyline declaration in the file with garbage and SOLDIWORKS will not complain.  It is only looking for solid geometry (e.g. IndexedFaceSet) and throws away all other types."

https://r1132100503382-eu1-3dswym.3dexperience.3ds.com/#community:yUw32GbYTEqKdgY7-jbZPg/iquestion:VokveX8JS82x7Pjqv9wS3w